# How can I configure a Xen image to run on EC2 with different drive names?

Tags: linux, amazon-ec2, xen, sles

I'm in the process of creating a number of Amazon Machine Images (AMIs) that will be uploaded and run on the basis of our Xen images. However, I'm running into problems with some platforms where the drive names assigned when they are running on EC2 are different than what Xen names them when we run the images locally.

For example, under SUSE running locally we see the following:

> brw-rw---- 1 root disk  202,   1 Jan 30 07:49 xvda1 
>   brw-rw---- 1 root disk  202,   2 Jan 30 07:49 xvda2 
>   brw-rw---- 1 root disk  202,   3 Jan 30 07:49 xvda3

While the Amazon supplied images report the following when running on a t1.micro:

> brw-rw---- 1 root disk   8,   1 Jan 30 13:18 sda1

How can I prepare my Xen images so that when we bundle them using [ec2-bundle-image](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/CommandLineReference/CLTRG-ami-bundle-image.html) the correct disk name will be automatically selected?

Answer (score 0):

The best approach is to not refer to drives by the actual names, but rather by the filesystem UUIDs or labels. These are exposed in `/dev/disk/by-uuid` and `/dev/disk/by-label` respectively, and can be specified in `/etc/fstab` with the `UUID=` or `LABEL=` syntax:

```
UUID=e6c4e981-ce1d-423e-9f23-167f8b370021   /   ext4    defaults    0   0
```

This is also accepted for the `root=` kernel parameter configured in the bootloader, so using GRUB1 for example:

```
kernel  /vmlinuz-3.2.0-31-virtual root=UUID=e6c4e981-ce1d-423e-9f23-167f8b370021 ro
```

GRUB2 and some patched versions of GRUB1 support UUIDs for finding the partition containing `/boot`. This shouldn't be a problem however since bootloaders don't name virtual disks differently.

Comment: Would this also work at boot time though? We ran into an issue with the `menu.lst` file referring to `/dev/xvda1` and causing the virtual machine to hang because it was `/dev/sda1/`

Comment: @RobZ Edited answer.